# Passing canvas to a function in onDraw method

Tags: android, canvas, view

There are two classes: Renderer which extends View and Grid. In the onDraw method of Renderer, I want to pass Canvas to the function of Grid. Since Java passes arguments only by value the code below does not work. I mean it does not draw a rectangle on the screen and says that program has stopped on my phone. Any idea?

```
public class Renderer extends View {

Paint paint;
Grid grid;

public Renderer(Context context, Grid grid) {
    super(context);
    paint = new Paint();
    this.grid = grid;
}

protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawRGB(255, 255, 255);      
    grid.tempName(canvas); // removing this solves problem
    invalidate();
}
}

public class Grid { 

Paint paint;

public void tempName (Canvas canvas) {

    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 200, paint);
}   
}
```

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding java pass-by-value. See this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference

Comment: The paint in grid might be null, maybe you're getting an NullPointerException. **AND** you should always tell us what the problem is or what the error message is, rather than just saying **doesn't work**

Comment: please post your logcat